# Mock embedded objects in integration test

Tags: java, spring, mockito

Trying to write an integration test for a Spring application. Say i've got a class A which contains a class B object. Class B contains a class C object and I need to mock an object within this class for the integration test - any idea how i go about doing that without passing every object through as a parameter in the constructor?

e.g.

```
@Service
Class A {
    @Autowired
    private B b;

    public void testA() {
        B.testB();
    }
}

@Service
Class B {
    @Autowired
    private C c;

    public void testB() {
        c.testC();
    }
}

@Service
Class C {

    //External class pulled in from dependency library
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public void testC() {
        restTemplate.doSomethingInOutsideWorld();
    }
}
```

Integration test:

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyIt {

    @ClassRule
    public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE = new SpringClassRule();

    @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();


    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private A a;

    @InjectMocks
    private C c;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() throws IOException {
        a.testA()
    }
}
```

Doesn't mock the `RestTemplate` object, it tries to hit the outside world. Any advice on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achieve this by using `SpringRunner` and `@MockBean`

**@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) is used to provide a bridge between Spring Boot test features and JUnit. Whenever we are using any Spring Boot testing features in out JUnit tests, this annotation will be required.**

**The @SpringBootTest annotation can be used when we need to bootstrap the entire container. The annotation works by creating the ApplicationContext that will be utilized in our tests.**

**Annotation that can be used to add mocks to a Spring ApplicationContext. Can be used as a class level annotation or on fields in either @Configuration classes, or test classes that are @RunWith the SpringRunner.**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyIt {

@MockBean
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Autowired
private A a;


@Before
public void setup() {
    initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void test1() throws IOException {

    given(this.restTemplate.doSomethingInOutsideWorld()).willReturn(custom object);
    a.testA()
   }
}
```